# Obtain the display value of a choice Field from a function within the own model

Tags: python, django

I have a method inside a model class, and I want to get the display value of a choice field in such model, but I get a weird value.

This is the code:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    PERSON = '0'
    ROLE = '1'
    AUTO = '2'
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (PERSON, 'Person'),
        (ROLE, 'Role'),
        (AUTO, 'Auto'),
    )
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    actor_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=PERSON)
    long_description = models.TextField(max_length=long_description_max_length, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_list_fields(self):
        list_fields = {
            'id' : self.id,
            'name' : self.alias,
            'description' : self.name,
            'extra_fields' : "[{}][{}]".format(
                self.email,
                getattr(self, 'get_actor_type_display')
            )
        }

        return list_fields
```

And this is the result i get:

```
{'id': 1, 
 'name': 'hugo', 
 'description': 'Hugo Luis Villalobos Canto', 
 'extra_fields': '[hugo@utopia-software.net][functools.partial(>, field=)]'
}
```

I don't know what that `functools.partial(>, field=)`stands for, and I don't know how to get the result I want: the display value of the current content of the field.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_list_fields(self):
        list_fields = {
            'id' : self.id,
            'name' : self.alias,
            'description' : self.name,
            'extra_fields' : "[{}][{}]".format(
                self.email,
                self.get_actor_type_display()
            )
        }

        return list_fields
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You need add parenthesis to call the `get_display` function :

```
def get_list_fields(self):
    list_fields = {
        'id' : self.id,
        'name' : self.alias,
        'description' : self.name,
        'extra_fields' : "[{}][{}]".format(
            self.email,
            getattr(self, 'get_actor_type_display()')
        )
    }
    return list_fields
```